# How should/must Catholics handle, transport, and use holy water?

Tags: catholicism, sacramentals

Some shrines, like the [Shrine of Padre Pio Chapel in Quezon City](https://www.facebook.com/pages/St-Padre-Pio-Chapel-Libis-QC/351607071557228), distribute holy water in bottles for Catholics who want some. So far the only guideline I saw in getting holy water from a basin is that to get one, you use a clean pitcher to scoop the water and pour it into the bottle. You do not sink the bottle into the basin of holy water until it gets full. But that is all.

How should/must observant Catholics handle, transport, and use holy water such that it won't get desecrated?

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you asked a priest or a deacon this question?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast not all of them, not recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question really deals with that of all blessed objects. Holy water is a [sacramental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramentals) of the Catholic Church.

Holy water should be treated like any other blessed sacramental object that is at our disposal!

> As Catholics, we are accustomed to having religious objects “blessed,” which signifies the permanent sanctification and dedication of an object for some sacred purpose. I think every weekend someone asks me as well as the other priests to bless a rosary, a statue, or some other religious object. Once a religious object is blessed and dedicated for divine worship or veneration, it must be treated with reverence and must not be used in either an improper or profane way (cf. Code of Canon Law, #1171).
>
> What happens when the rosary or statue breaks and is irreparable? Or, when the palm dries out, and the following Palm Sunday provides us with new palm? The basic rule for the disposition of these items is to burn or to bury them.
>   - [Fr. Joseph Edattu, VC](http://www.drcm.org/divine-call-archive/657-how-to-treat-sacred-objects-and-relics)

Personally, I have some holy water in my home and in my car at all times. I am sure that many priests do this also, as it is never known as to when one might have a need for it. I even know of one priest that carries holy water on his person in a holy water sprinkler the size of a [pen](https://www.catholiccompany.com/holy-water-items-c5308/)!

Comment: In some parishes, including mine, it is customary to bring last year's dried-out palms to church on Quinquagesima Sunday, the last Sunday before lent begins.  The palms are then burned to produce the ashes for Ash Wednesday.

Comment: You may wish to refer to the CCC rather than Wikipedia regarding [sacramental](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c4a1.htm)

Answer (score 1):

> Some shrines, like the Shrine of Padre Pio Chapel in Quezon City,
>   distribute holy water in bottles for Catholics who want some.

In Italy more or less all churches used to distribute holy water in bottles. According to my knowledge there isn't a correct way for using or for handle, the only thing is to use and treat with *respect*.

Source: my knowledge.